# VBA: Convert snippet from VBA to SQL

Tags: sql, vba, t-sql, vb6

I have a small If statement that I would like to ask for help to convert it to SQL syntax.

If I am correct, the If statement checks for the position where a period on the string passed might be found. If found (> 0) e.g. string: "VQAL1-SQ994.1", would be 12 so > 0 would be true, then can someone explain to me what the output of:         Id = Left(ID, InStr(ID, ".") - 1) wuld be given the example string?

```
If InStr(ID, ".") > 0 Then 
    Id = Left(ID, InStr(ID, ".") - 1)
End If
```

Thank you for your help.

**UPDATE**

I put together a small stored procedure to see if I was able to make this work, but so far I think it is not working because it returns nothing from the string I pass.

Test execute:

```
/*
EXEC Test_String  'VQAL1-SQ994.1'
*/
```

Stored Procedure contents:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test_String] (@ProductID VARCHAR(25))
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @ID VARCHAR (25)
    SET @ID = (
                      SELECT
                        LEFT(@ProductID, LEN(@ProductID) - LEN(REPLACE(@ProductID, '.', '')) - 1)
                     );

    SELECT @ID;
END;
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx

Comment: Your posted code seems to differ from your description - seems more like a `Split(ID, ".")(0)` operation, not just "remove period"

Comment: I might be wrong in my explanation of what the code is doing, my bad. That is how I understood the vb code. Please if the code is actually doing something different let me know. The existent code actually uses a Instr function, not a Split function.

Comment: Your code is recovering everything to the left of the dot character - like the first part of a filename

Comment: Use suggestions from @Tim Williams link - might have to adjust for non SQL Server - you didn't say what SQL you're using

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2012. I think the function to use would be CHARINDEX.

Comment: I'm no VB expert, but isn't that getting the first X characters of the string, where X = count of periods - 1?

Comment: Using your example "VQAL1-SQ994.1" your VB code returns "VQAL1-SQ994" ie. everything to the left of the first period.

Comment: Yes that is true. The SQL that I updated the question wit, returns a blank value when the same string is passed, and if the value has no periods then it throws an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it's returning the first X characters of the string, with X being count of periods - 1. In TSQL you can do this via:

```
SELECT Left(id, LEN(id) - Len(Replace(id, '.', '')) - 1)
```

Comment: I updated my question to show what I am doing when migrating the VB code to a stored procedure in sql server 2012.

Comment: What you have looks correct now. If you pass in a string with 3 periods in it, you'll get the first 2 characters of the string you passed in. If the string you pass in has 22 periods, you'll get the first 21 characters, etc. It mimics what the VBA code you posted does.

Comment: But if I pass a string: VQAL1-SQ994.1, then is passes a blank value. When it is supposed to pass everything to the left of the period. And if I pass a string that does not contains a period: VQAL1-SQ994, then it throws a message: Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: Yes, you'd still need to wrap this in the IF logic. Your original code didn't do anything to the string if there were no periods. And the blank is getting returned because 1-1=0. If you want everything before the first period, use SELECT
                        LEFT(@ProductID, CharIndex('.', @productID)-1)

Comment: Perfect. That seems to be working. Thank you Jeffrey.

Answer (score 2):

```
REPLACE(yourstringcolumn, '.', '')
```

[Replace on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx)

Comment: Initially question was "how to replace characters in a string", which explains this answer.